# Image download using S3 url

Tags: reactjs, typescript, amazon-s3, react-hooks

In my project I am trying to download the image, for that added the following lines,

```
const downloadImage = (image: string) => {
    const a = window.document.createElement("a");
    const blob = new Blob([image], { type: "octet/stream" });
    console.log("blob", blob);
    const x = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    console.log("x", x);
    a.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    a.download = "image.png";
    document.body.appendChild(a);
    a.click();
  };
```

Here the image is downloaded but when it opens then it looks like this,

[image]

Also when I console values
[image]

Please give me some solution to fix this issue.

Comment: Im guessing `image` is just a URL to the image? You currently are trying to basically download a text file which contains the URL, not the image data.

Comment: Then how to change the code to download the image? the image variable contains the url of image.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are overcomplicating things and have some odd amalgamation of multiple approaches. If the `image` variable is just A url then you can just render a link with the download attribute directly in your JSX.

```
<a href={image} download>Download</a>
```

Comment: But when I use <a> tag the image opens in a new tab instead of downloading.